# Pagination page/2 not found for a category but works for tags?

Tags: pagination, tags

This drives me nuts, i am trying to list post based on a category an on a tag. Now for tag i have got it working. Using archive.php but for the category, using categroy.php, it doesn't work for page/2???.

I have already check the permalinks and indeed if i use the default settings both mydomain.com/blog/page/2 and mydomain.com/tag/green/page/2 work. But turning on /%category%/%postname%/ and the mydomain.com/blog/page/2 gives a page not found???

Here's the main part of category.php (which is the same as archive.php)

```
     global $wp_query;
               $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                query_posts(array(

                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'paged' => $paged
                ));

                while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                    // Include the page content template.
                    get_template_part('partials/content', 'loop');

                // End the loop.
                endwhile;
                ?>
                <!-- Pagination -->
                <div class="navigation">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
            </div>
<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged')); ?>
                <div class="older"><?php next_posts_link(__('Older entries', 0)); ?></div>
<!--test this one-->
                <?php if ($paged > 1) : ?>
                    <div class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer entries', 0)); ?></div>
                <?php endif;
            endif;
            ?>
            <!-- End Pagination -->
```

Comment: hmm the old plugin Category pagination fix seems to fix my problem, but what is the underlying problem???

ps: admin this thread should be on wordpress.sta

Answer (score -1):

The codex contains the following important note on [`query_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like making use of pre_get_postshook, for this purpose.

If you follow that instruction, you should be able to fix your problem yourself